# mysql: Limit to maximum equal results of multiple queries

Tags: mysql

```
Name   Age     Work    Eyes
---------------------------
John   young  home   black

Mike  young   home   blue

Irvin   old   home   black

Marie  young  home   blue

Teddy  old   factory  green
```

Multiple checkbox form, search term1=young, term2=home, term3=blue

```
 SELECT   Name 
 FROM     my_table 
 WHERE    (Age = 'young')
       OR (Work = 'home')
       OR (Eyes = 'blue') 
 ORDER BY (Age = 'young')
        + (Work = 'home')
        + (Eyes = 'blue') DESC LIMIT 1
```

In my case two results are with maximum-equal coincidences (Mike and Marie) I want to show both of them.
How to LIMIT for most frequently results? Could be only one or many: 2,3...equal coincidences 
 off:thanks eggyal for ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution without scanning the whole table (twice). Here's one:

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM 
    my_table AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX((Age = 'young') + (Work = 'home') + (Eyes = 'blue')) AS matching
      FROM my_table
    ) AS m
    ON  m.matching > 0  
    AND m.matching = (t.Age = 'young') + (t.Work = 'home') + (t.Eyes = 'blue')
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery can be a simple way of doing this sort of thing. What you're really looking for is all entries where the value of (Age = 'young') + (Work = 'home') + (Eyes = 'blue') equals the highest value across all entries.

```
SELECT Name
FROM my_table
WHERE
    Age = 'young'
    OR Work = 'home'
    OR Eyes = 'blue'
    AND ( (Age = 'young') + (Work = 'home') + (Eyes = 'blue') ) = (
            SELECT MAX((Age = 'young') + (Work = 'home') + (Eyes = 'blue'))
            FROM my_table
        )
```

Comment: Is not exactly what I want. In table above for those 3 search terms  I want to have only 2 search results (Mike and Marie). In another case on next search for ex. "young", "factory","green" the search result must be only one:"Teddy"; in another case with "young", "home". "green" must be only 3 rows: Jonh, Mike, Marie. Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: i think this answer is correct, only the parentheses are wrong `(Age = 'young' OR Work = 'home' OR Eyes = 'blue') AND (...)` will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get results based on similarities, the following will give you a result but I had to write all the combinations so in real case scenario you will need to have `n! + 1`* conditions.

> **n!** stands for *"factorial"* and for example **3!** means **3 * 2 * 1 = 6**
>   and **+1** is for the whole match (3 in your case)

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    1 AS '_Age',1 AS '_Work',1 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Age`,`Work`,`Eyes`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    1 AS '_Age',1 AS '_Work',0 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Age`,`Work`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    1 AS '_Age',0 AS '_Work',1 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Age`,`Eyes`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    0 AS '_Age',1 AS '_Work',1 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Work`,`Eyes`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    1 AS '_Age',0 AS '_Work',0 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Age`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    0 AS '_Age',1 AS '_Work',0 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Work`
HAVING `matches` > 1

UNION

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ' - ') AS 'Names',
    COUNT(*) AS 'matches',
    0 AS '_Age',0 AS '_Work',1 AS '_Eyes'
FROM `my_table` WHERE
    `Age`='young' OR
    `Work`='home' OR
    `Eyes`='blue'
GROUP BY `Eyes`
HAVING `matches` > 1

ORDER BY
    `_Age`+`_Work`+`_Eyes` DESC,
    `matches` DESC
```

And the result will be

```
|            Names            | matches | _Age | _Work | _Eyes |
+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| Mike - Marie                |    2    |   1  |   1   |   1   |
| John - Mike - Marie         |    3    |   1  |   1   |   0   |
| Mike - Marie                |    2    |   1  |   0   |   1   |
| John - Irvin                |    2    |   0  |   1   |   1   |
| Mike - Marie                |    2    |   0  |   1   |   1   |
| John - Mike - Irvin - Marie |    4    |   0  |   1   |   0   |
| John - Mike - Marie         |    3    |   1  |   0   |   0   |
| Mike - Marie                |    2    |   0  |   0   |   1   |
| John - Irvin                |    2    |   0  |   0   |   1   |
```

This is not extremely practical but I don't know how you can get name combinations by any other approach.